# Why do the wavelengths of lights oscillate wrt atmospheric penetration?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, physical-chemistry

Funnily enough, I was reading about Jungian Archetypes when I happened upon this diagram:

[image]

I had not previously seen this and I couldn't find much information on it nor why it is occurring, I'd imagine a result of the chemical makeup? Why do the wavelengths and energies at which light can penetrate oscillate?

Comment: @hisairmessag3 what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Are you asking why the top bar in that diagram is YNYN?

Comment: @PM2Ring This is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a fair number of mechanisms by which electromagnetic radiation can get absorbed in the atmosphere (or reflected by it).  A *partial* set of mechanisms is:

- electronic transitions (incoming photons kick electrons into higher orbits, ionize atoms or molecules or break molecular bonds), which work for UV & visible wavelengths, as well as shorter wavelengths (X-rays);
- molecular vibrations (incoming photons excite vibrational modes in molecules) which work for short infrared wavelengths;
- molecular rotations (incoming photons excite rotational modes in molecules) which works for far infrared & microwave wavelengths.

There are others, and in particular for very long wavelengths (what we think of as 'radio waves' the atmosphere (specifically the ionosphere) can reflect rather than absorb radiation, which is why things like shortwave radio can work over long distances.

As you can see all of these are frequency-dependent, and many of them also depend on the composition of the atmosphere.  The end result of all this is that the amount of EM radiation which gets absorbed (or reflected) by a given thickness of atmosphere depends on the composition of the atmosphere and the frequency of the radiation in a fairly complicated way.  It is possible to compute & measure various quantities which describe this, such as the [optical depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_depth) which tells you how much gets through a given thickness of atmosphere at a given frequency and which in turn is related to the [attenuation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient), which tells you how much gets through per unit length.

The end result of all this computation and measurement is that you can calculate & measure how opaque the atmosphere is for a given wavelength, and you end up with a plot like the one on [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(electromagnetic_radiation)).

A significant feature of this plot is that there are 'windows' in it: parts of the spectrum where EM waves penetrate rather well.  It's experimentally obvious that there is at least one such window because we can see the Sun and the stars, so light is getting right through the atmosphere from them to us.  In fact the visible-light window extends down into the infrared somewhat, with some bumps, and there's then a patch in the IR where the atmosphere is opaque, before becoming more-or-less transparent again in a good chunk of the radio spectrum.

These two windows are the bits of your diagram marked by 'Y', and I think they're really the only two big windows (I might be wrong about that).

So how transparent the atmosphere is to various frequencies does not really 'oscillate': rather there are a number of mechanisms which make it more-or-less opaque, which mechanisms depend on frequency (or, in other words, photon energy), and these mechanisms, based on the composition of the atmosphere, combine to give two big windows where the atmosphere is more-or-less transparent while being more-or-less opaque at other frequencies.

---

This is a large subject area and the subject of a lot of work as almost anyone who cares about what electromagnetic radiation gets through the atmosphere is interested in some part of the problem, from people studying climate to astronomers to people designing radio communications systems.  I suspect that [Absorption of electromagnetic radiation](https://doi.org/10.1036/1097-8542.001600) by William West may be a good reference, but I have not read it.  The references in [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(electromagnetic_radiation)) I previously mentioned are perhaps a good place to start.